# Trying to loop over several files execute a command on each file and concat the output to same str variable

Tags: python, bash

`flake8_errs` is the variable initialized to empty string ('').

Trying to concat the output of the command

`flake8 --config=$(CI_DIR)/lint-configs/python/.flake8 $$py_file;`

on each `.py` file to `flake8_errs` variable.

Then check if `flake8_errs` has some content and raise an err.

**This is what I tried so far:**

```
flake8_errs =''
.PHONY: .flake8
.flake8:
    . $(VIRTUALENV_DIR)/bin/activate; \
    if [ "$${FORCE_CHECK_ALL_FILES}" = "true" ]; then \
        find ./* -name "*.py" | while read py_file; do \
            flake8_errs += flake8 --config=$(CI_DIR)/lint-configs/python/.flake8 $$py_file; \
        done; \
    else \
        echo "No files have changed, skipping run..."; \
    fi;
    if [ ! -z "${flake8_errs}" ]; then \
        exit 1; \
    fi;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use make functions in a recipe, and you can't assign to make variables in a recipe.  Recipes are fully expanded once so all make constructs are resolved, then the shell is invoked and given the results of that expansion, then make waits for the shell to finish to determine whether it worked.

You can't "intersperse" shell and makefile content, where the shell would have to run some things, then make constructs would be expanded, then the shell would run more things, etc.

You should write the entire rule using **ONLY** shell constructs:

```
.PHONY: .flake8
.flake8:
        . $(VIRTUALENV_DIR)/bin/activate; \
        files='$(CHANGED_PY)'; \
        if [ '$(FORCE_CHECK_ALL_FILES)' = true ]; then \
            files="$$(find ./* -name "*.py")"; \
        fi; \
        if [ -z "$$files" ]; then \
            echo "No files have changed, skipping run..."; \
            exit 0; \
        fi; \
        errors=; \
        for file in $$files; do \
            if [ -n "$$file" ]; then \
                errors="$$errors $$(flake8 --config=$(CI_DIR)/lint-configs/python/.flake8 $$file)"; \
            fi; \
        done; \
        if [ -n "$$errors" ]; then \
           echo "got errors: $$errors"; \
           exit 1; \
        fi;
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it.
And how can I validate it is not empty?
`
    if [ ! -z "${flake8_errs}" ]; then \
       exit 1; \
    fi;
`
?

Comment: `$(if $(flake8_errs),,$(error empty flake8))`

Comment: (I think you meant `if [ -z "$(flake8_errs)" ]`; what you wrote would exit if the variable had content)

Comment: I meant to check if it doesn't empty raise an err.

Doesn't seems to work (am I missing something?)

recieving:
 /bin/sh: 2: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
make: *** [Makefile:71: .flake8] Error 2

(Edited main thread)

Comment: Somehow you put the text I showed into a shell script.  It's make syntax, not shell syntax.  I'll edit my answer but you should really read the docs.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to go through all that trouble to compute flake8 flags then raise an error if it _ISN'T_ empty (that is, raise an error if any flags were found) but that's what you said so that's what I put in my answer edit.  Anyway, I think you probably need to ask another question with more detail about what exactly you want to do and why if this isn't sufficient.

Comment: Oh, I see.  You're trying to write a rule that performs flake8 checking.  My answer is completely wrong for that.  Being more precise in your question the first time would be very helpful.

Comment: I think your answer is good or at least this is the direction. I just have a lack of Makefiles behavior.
I want to iterate and populate all flake8 errs, 
Once I have at least one err I want to raise err i.e exit1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228902/discussion-between-david-meu-and-madscientist).